# how to select records that occurs 3 times and combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This is my table

```
create table student
(
stu_id int,
s_name nvarchar(max),
s_subject nvarchar(max),
marks int
)
```

and rows are --

```
stu_id  s_name  s_subject   marks
123 Sam English     86
123 Sam Maths       93
123 Sam Chemistry   85
124 Emma    Biology     80
125 Abbey   Physics     90
125 Abbey   Computer    95
125 Abbey   ED      75
```

I want rows of students which appear more than twice.

I want this:

```
stu_id  s_name  s_subject                marks
123 Sam English,Maths,Chemistry      86,93,85               
125 Abbey   Physics,Computer,ED      90,95,75
```

What I have done is

```
DECLARE @sub_list AS varchar(MAX) -- Leave as NULL
DECLARE @marks_list AS varchar(MAX)

SELECT @sub_list = COALESCE(@sub_list + ',', '') + CONVERT(varchar, s_subject),
@marks_list = COALESCE(@marks_list + ',', '') + CONVERT(varchar, marks)

FROM student where stu_id in (
    select stu_id 
    from student
    group by stu_id
    having count(stu_id) > 2
) 
select @sub_list as Subject_ ,@marks_list as Marks;
```

and I get bad result..

```
Subject_                    Marks
English,Maths,Chemistry,Physics,Computer,ED 86,93,85,90,95,75
```

Please help I am trying since morning....

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this example will help:

```
DECLARE @people TABLE(id INT, NAME NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT @people VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'Mary')

DECLARE @cars TABLE(ownerId INT, NAME NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT @cars VALUES (1, 'Toyota'), (1, 'Lada'), (2, 'Nissan'), (2, 'Mazda'), (2, 'Buick')

SELECT 
    Id,
    Name,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ','+name
        FROM @Cars c
        WHERE c.OwnerId = p.Id
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') AS OwnedCars
FROM @people p
```

**Regarding your case:**

```
;WITH Students(Id, Name) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT stu_id, s_name
    FROM Student
)

SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ','+s_subject
        FROM student
        WHERE student.stu_id = Students.Id
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') AS s_subjects,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ','+CAST(marks AS varchar)
        FROM student
        WHERE student.stu_id = Students.Id
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') AS marks
FROM Students
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select S1.stu_id,
       S1.s_name,
       stuff((select ','+S2.s_subject
              from student as S2
              where S2.stu_id = S1.stu_id
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as s_subject,
       stuff((select ','+cast(S2.marks as varchar(max))
              from student as S2
              where S2.stu_id = S1.stu_id
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as marks
from student as S1
group by S1.stu_id, S1.s_name
having count(*) >= 3
```

Try on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62802/concatenate-students)